# php create array and sub array from string

Tags: php

I want to convert a string to an array. I want an array that has a sub array like this :

my string :

```
field=3,icon=[class='test',svg=null],test=[pass='345',username='salar']
```

to :

```
array("field"=> 3,"icon"=> [ "class" =>  "test", "svg" => null ], "test"=> [ "pass" =>  "345", "username" => 'salar' ] )
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read our [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get a better understanding about how to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Please show us what you've tried.

Comment: Where is the input format from? Instead maybe it could be better to use some more common like JSON?

Comment: Where is this string coming from?  Maybe instead of generating a string like this, you could have it generate a JSON string or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would *highly* suggest changing the string format being generated.  It's better to use an existing format like JSON than to create/parse your own format.

Speaking of JSON, one way to "parse" this format is to *convert* it to JSON and then parse that.

So, convert the `=` to `:`, wrap all keys (and values) in `""`, convert `[]` to `{}`, and then wrap the whole thing in `{}`.

```
<?php
$data = "field=3,icon=[class='test',svg=null],test=[pass='345',username='salar']";

// Fix quotes
$jsonData = str_replace("'", '"', $data);

// Convert arrays to objects
$jsonData = str_replace(['[', ']'], ['{', '}'], $jsonData);

// Fix keys
$jsonData = preg_replace("/(^|,|{)(.+?)=/", '$1"$2":', $jsonData);

// Parse as JSON
$result = json_decode('{' . $jsonData . '}', true);
```

Comment: thank you! This code was great and it was exactly what I wanted